# Create .eml file without saving EmailMessage to a mailbox first

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, eml

My goal is to take message parameters (from, to, body, subject, etc) and create a .eml file.

I am currently using EWS managed API (though I am open to other suggestions) to create an EmailMessage object.  Instead of saving the message to a mailbox or sending it (this is not possible because the application's account which I am using doesn't have access to any mailboxes due to security policies), I want to create a .eml file.

I adapted some code I found from another answer which looked promising:

```
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);

//message initialization code
//...

using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"message.eml", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))  
{
    message.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent));
    var mc = message.MimeContent;
    fs.Write(mc.Content, 0, mc.Content.Length);
}
```

But I get an exception on the message.Load() saying "This operation can't be performed because this service object doesn't have an Id."  Through a little debugging I basically see that message.Id is null.  Id does not have a setter.  I believe this is because the message doesn't get an ID until it is saved to a folder, which I cannot do.

Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The EmailMessage class doesn't have a MIME parser/writer. The MimeContent is created by the server. The workaround is to create your own parser to parse out the properties set on EmailMessage object. Why use the EmailMessage class if you aren't saving to the server?

Comment: I used the EmailMessage class since I thought it had a method to generate the MimeContent and save to an eml file (the Load method).  Is there a way to leverage whatever logic is generating the MimeContent by the server without saving to it?  If not, are there guidelines/documentation as to how to properly format an eml file?  (My understanding was not necessarily)  Thanks

Comment: My understanding is the .eml format is based on RFC822 (http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822.txt) or one of its successor RFCs. You may try to look to see if anyone has made an EmailMessage to .eml parser, or you can inspect a .eml file (it is plain text) so you can create your own parse.